# TimelinePlot; How to control what happens when the mouse hovers over an entry?

Tags: plotting, graphics

When you hover over an event in a `TimelinePlot` the border around the event thickens and a `Tooltip` message gives the date.  How can I control the format of the change and the message?

What I would like is for the event to grow bigger and the date to be shown in a simple way. I don't want a `Tooltip` message.

Here is some data and a display to work with.

```
test = {
   {{1947} -> "Flutter"},
   {{1940} -> "Tacoma Narrows"},
   {{1954} -> "Fatigue (Comet)"},
   {Interval[{{1912}, {2020}}] -> "Electronic Amplifiers"},
   {{1930} -> "Oscilloscope"},
   {Interval[{{1930}, {1985}}] -> "Analogue Testing"},
   {{1945} -> "Accelerometer"},
   {Interval[{{1985}, {2020}}] -> "Digital Testing"},
   {Interval[{{1975}, {2020}}] -> "Digital Signal Processing"},
   {{1965} -> "Fast Fourier Transform"},
   {Interval[{{1990}, {1986}}] -> "Codification of Testing"},
   {{2012} -> "San Onofre Steam Generators"}
   }; 

simulation = {
   {Interval[{{1950}, {1990}}] -> "Main Frames"},
   {Interval[{{1900}, {1970}}] -> "Slide Rules"},
   {Interval[{{1970}, {1980}}] -> "Electronic Calculators"},
   {Interval[{{1985}, {2020}}] -> "Workstations"},
   {{1964} -> "NASTRAN"},
   {Interval[{{1983}, {2020}}] -> "NAFEMS"},
   {{1960} -> "Finite Element Analysis"},
   {{2006} -> "ASME Verification and Validation"}
   };

Framed@Show[TimelinePlot[#1,
     AxesOrigin -> #2, AxesLabel -> {"Year", " "}] & @@@ {{test, 
     Bottom}, {simulation, Top}},
  AspectRatio -> 1/2, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 24},
  PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False, Axes -> {True, False}, 
  ImageSize -> 20 72,
  Epilog -> {
    Style[Text["Test", {-1*^8, 26}], FontSize -> 30],
    Style[Text["Analysis", {-1*^8, -18}], FontSize -> 30]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: do you get what you need if you change the first argument of `Show` from `#` to `TimelinePlot[Tooltip[#,Row[{DateString[#,{ "Year"}]&/@(#[[1,1]]/. Interval ->Identity),#[[1,2]]}, ":"]]&/@# ,  AxesOrigin -> #2, AxesLabel -> {"Year", " "}] & @@@ {{test,  Bottom}, {simulation, Top}}`?

Comment: This gives me a good ToolTip message but unfortunately  I don't want one! This is for showing to an audience. So I just need the words in the box made bigger and  the date added.  Is that possible?  Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove tooltips using the option `PerformanceGoal ->"Speed"` and pre-process the input data to wrap labels with `Mouseover`:

```
toMouseover = # /. Rule[a_, b_] :> Rule[a, 
  Mouseover[b, Row[Style[#, Red, 24] & /@ {b, " : ", 
     If[Head[a] === Interval, Flatten @@ a, ## & @@ a]}]]] &;

Style[Framed@Show[TimelinePlot[toMouseover@#, AxesOrigin->#2, AxesLabel -> {"Year", " "},
       PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"] & @@@ {{test, Bottom}, {simulation, Top}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> False, 
   Axes -> {True, False}, ImageSize -> 20 72, 
   Epilog -> {Style[Text["Test", {-1*^8, 26}], FontSize -> 30], 
     Style[Text["Analysis", {-1*^8, -18}], FontSize -> 30]}], 
 Magnification -> 2/3]
```

[image]